# Text file is getting downloaded from web but issue with ePub/Pdf

Tags: java, android, file, download, epub

I'm referring following code to download a file from particular URL.

```
public class FileFromServerExample extends Activity {

    static String PACKAGE_NAME;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();        

        File folder = new File("/data/data/"
                + FileFromServerExample.PACKAGE_NAME + "/ePub/");
        boolean created = folder.isDirectory();
        if (!created) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        File file = new File(folder, "Sample.epub");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Downloader
                .DownloadFile(
                        "http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sample%20epub%20filetype%3Aepub&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F1177388%2Fflagship_july_4_2010_flying_island_press.epub&ei=i5gHUIOWJI3RrQeGro3YAg&usg=AFQjCNFPKsV-tieF4vKv7BXYmS-QEvd7Uw",
                        file);
}
}
```

---

**Downloader.java**

```
public class Downloader {

    public static void DownloadFile(String fileURL, File directory) {
        try {

            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            URL u = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

I'm getting `Sample.epub` at desired location.
 But when I try to open that file, I got an error message stating **Not a valid zip file**.

I tried with various URL's, with `Pdf` instead of `ePub` (it gives **file corrupted error**), but    the same problem persists.

However, when I tried to download a simple text file from [this sample link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/readme.txt) , it works properly.

So by common sense, it appears that **[this URL](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sample%20epub%20filetype%3Aepub&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F1177388%2Fflagship_july_4_2010_flying_island_press.epub&ei=i5gHUIOWJI3RrQeGro3YAg&usg=AFQjCNFPKsV-tieF4vKv7BXYmS-QEvd7Uw)** to download `ePub` might be broken, but that's not the case as I successfully downloaded the `ePub` if I visit the link from my PC's browser. 
However when I try to download the `ePub` from this link in android application, it doesn't work.

Any idea, where I'm going wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: on which android OS you are testing?

Comment: android 2.3... but how does it matter?

Comment: because android > 3.0 does not allow web request on `Main UI Thread` That is `why I just checking of this possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because you are not pointing to a direct url. instead in browsers, google redirects to the original url. in your case the original link is:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1177388/flagship_july_4_2010_flying_island_press.epub

if you try to download this direct url, you will succeed.

Comment: oh gosh... how can i make such a silly mistake... but I googled for free epub samples, i opened one of the links and i got above link(specified in question) from address bar... how u got this link?

Comment: heyy nothing fancy has done here. just took the `url` get parameter from the googled link and then `URLDecode`d the copied `epub` link. just used the online service from here: http://www.string-functions.com/urldecode.aspx

Comment: 'output is same as input' ? what does that mean ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14159/discussion-between-sunil-and-gama)

Comment: @GAMA heyy... not like that. plz read my above comment carefully. you have to take out the `URL` parameter (one from the `GET` parameter list) of `google` search url. your original searched URL was : http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sample%20epub%20filetype%3Aepub&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F1177388%2Fflagship_july_4_2010_flying_island_press.epub&ei=i5gHUIOWJI3RrQeGro3YAg&usg=AFQjCNFPKsV-tieF4vKv7BXYmS-QEvd7Uw. now take the `URL` parameter from this.

Comment: now you will get the URL as `http%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F1177388%2Fflagship_july_4_2010_flying_island_press.epub`. paste this in (http://www.string-functions.com/urldecode.aspx) and press decode. you will get the decoded url